# Django: Overwriting a form. how to shortening the mapping of the fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am testing forms and model nesting in django.

Due to a ManyToMany Relation in my form i have to use a custom save function. So far it works. But i asked myself if there is a way to shorten the code? So here is my my...

> forms.py

```
GuestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dish = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    # --- Input for meal.table
    table_input = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = [ 
            'name',
            'dish',
            'table_input',
            'city',
            'department'
            ]


     # --- Dish names from dish.model
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dish'].queryset = Dish.objects.all()


    def save(self):
        # --- save the new Meal.object
        data = self.cleaned_data
        mealData = Meal(table=data['table_input'], dish=data['dish'])
        mealData.save()

        # --- save the new Guest.object 
        guestData = Guest(name=data['name'], city=data['city'], department=data['department'])
        guestData.save()

        # --- add a m2m relation between Guest.object and Meal.object
        guestData.meals.add(mealData)
        guestData.save()

        return guestData
```

> **Question**

My Question is especially related to the mapping of all fields after i saved `mealData.save()`.

```
# --- save the new Guest.object 
guestData = Guest(name=data['name'], city=data['city'], department=data['department'])
guestData.save()
```

Because in bigger Projects it could mean a lot of work, to map every field afterwards, just because i needed `table`and `dish`to save in a extra model. 
Or in other Words is there some Kind of Selection Method? Something like "all Data Fields still relating to `Meta: model = Guest` minus these from `mealData`"?
I don´t know maybe something like these?

```
# --- Select all other fields and save the new Guest.object 
guestData = Guest.minus(guestData)
guestData.save()
```

Comment: Your form is a ModelForm for the model Guest, so you only need to do `guestData = super().save()` to have your `guestData` object saved. But for `Meal` there is no shortcut, really, you have to instantiate a `Meal` with the correct attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is a `ModelForm` for the model `Guest`, so it "knows" how to save a `Guest` even when there are additional fields and additional data submitted: `super().save()` will actually save your model instance and return it. For `mealData` there's no shortcut.

```
 def save(self, commit=True):
     guestData = super().save(commit)  # this saves the model
     mealData = ...
     if commit:
         mealData.save()
         guestData.meals.add(mealData)  # no need to save guestData again!
     return guestData
```

Now I added the `commit` parameter because that's good practice for model forms (someone writing the view should be able to call `save(commit=False)` on your form).

Note that your `fields` attribute on the `Meta` class contains fields that do not belong to the `Guest` model (`dish` and `table_input`), you should remove them. Only model fields should appear there.